# convert Word document to .pdf

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am not able to read Microsoft Word page by page and write into PDF file.
I am having Apache poi jar 3.15 and itext jar 5.0.6. In Apache poi,i am having 5 jars namely poi-3.14.jar,poi-ooxml-3.14.jar,poi-ooxml-schemas-3.14.jar ,XmlBeans 2.6.0.jar.Poi Scratchpad 3.14.jar My code is shown below.

```
                 public class Script
                 {
                 public void WordToPdf()
                 {
                 POIFSFileSystem fs = null;  
                 Document document = new Document();
                 try
                 {  
                 System.out.println("Starting the test");  
                fs = new POIFSFileSystem(new       FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\Srieedher.doc"));  

         HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(fs);  
         WordExtractor we = new WordExtractor(doc);  

         OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\test.pdf")); 

         PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, file);  

          }
         catch (Exception e) {  
         System.out.println("Exception during test");  
         e.printStackTrace();  
         }
         finally
          {  
           document.close();  
           }  

          }

         public static void main(String args[])
         {
         Script1 s=new Script();
         s1.WordToPdf();
         }
         }
```

Comment: By titling the question "Java Programming Concept" and having poorly indented code isn't going to help you get the answer questioned - could you edit the question to make it more answer-friendly?

Comment: What details  you want exactly Jerrybibo

Comment: "I am not able to read Microsoft Word page by page and write into PDF file." How exactly? What error messages are you getting? Or are you getting no results? Please give us your current output and the expected output of the program.

Comment: Jerry bibo-  iam getting Output. In a Microsoft Word file , i am giving 3 pages of content ,but when i am writing into PDFfile all the contents are coming in first page only. I want 1st page of Microsoft Word to read and  write into 1st page of Pdf. When iam reading 2nd page of MS word, same thing should  write into PDF file.

Comment: POI does not have a concept of a page of text. That depends on the size of the paper, font size, line spacing, etc. So you can't read a page of text in POI. You can extract the text from the document, but you have to render it to pages yourself. POI will not help with this.

Comment: Likewise POI does not even have the concept of a line of text. Once again that depends on the rendering of that text.